# Kubernetes size definitions: What's the difference of "Gi" and "G"?

Tags: kubernetes

While I explored yaml definitions of Kubernetes templates, I stumbled across different definitions of sizes. First I thought it's about the apiVersions but they are the same. So what is the difference there? Which are right when both are the same?

`storage: 5G` and `storage: 5Gi`

```
volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: mongo-persistent-storage
    spec:
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 2Gi
```

see here in detail: 
https://github.com/cvallance/mongo-k8s-sidecar/blob/master/example/StatefulSet/mongo-statefulset.yaml

and this one:

```
 volumeClaimTemplates:
 - metadata:
     name: mongo-persistent-storage
   spec:
     resources:
       requests:
         storage: 5G
```

here in detail: https://github.com/openebs/openebs/blob/master/k8s/demo/mongodb/mongo-statefulset.yml

Comment: Not sure in the Kubernetes context, but in some contexts there is a distinction between "Gi"/"GiB" = 1024 Mebibyte (Memory & File system counting) and "G"/"GB" = 1000 Megabyte ("HDD storage" counting). "G"/"GB" is often ambiguously used to refer to either :}

Comment: Make sense now, thank you! When I understand everything correctly, I had to remember the „short“ version, when I handle with Hard Disk storage values like mongodb disk spaces? And which answer should I accept so honor the right person?

Comment: FWIW, my "scoring" goes something like this, with earlier having a higher weight: correct answer to the actual question asked, excerpt with reference documentation/link (-1 point for just links), further explanation / supporting information / specific examples, grammar and formatting, frist.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

From [Kubernetes source](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/):

> Limits and requests for memory are measured in bytes. You can express
> memory as a plain integer or as a fixed-point integer using one of
> these suffixes: E, P, T, G, M, K. **You can also use the power-of-two
> equivalents**: Ei, Pi, Ti, Gi, Mi, Ki. For example, the following
> represent **roughly** the same value:
>
> 128974848, 129e6, 129M, 123Mi

So those are the "bibyte" counterparts, like user2864740 commented.

A [little info](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kibibyte) on those orders of magnitude:

> The kibibyte was designed to replace the kilobyte in those computer
> science contexts in which the term kilobyte is used to mean 1024
> bytes. The interpretation of kilobyte to denote 1024 bytes,
> **conflicting with the SI definition of the prefix kilo (1000)**, used to
> be common.

So, as you can see, 5G means 5 Gigabytes while 5Gi means 5 Gibibytes. They amount to:

- 5 G = 5000000 KB / 5000 MB
- 5 Gi = 5368709.12 KB / 5368.70 MB

Therefore, in terms of size, they are not the same.

But don't worry if you don't understand the differences at first read. Even Windows gets it wrong!

[image]

Comment: Any way to ask for the output to be expressed in one unit ? Say in Mi and not in M nor in Gi

Comment: If 1Gi is 1024 then 5Gi should be 5120 not 5368.70. What am I missing?

Comment: You are missing the measure unit of your results. Indeed, 5Gi are equal to 5120 **mebibytes** (MiB), **and** 5368.70 **megabytes** (MB). See: https://www.gbmb.org/mib-to-mb

Comment: units of measurement for ephemeral storage - this should be the default answer for any search engine. see this link for answer on [bibytes why are they a thing?](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-Bibytes-such-as-Kibibytes-Mebibytes-exist-when-Kilobytes-and-Megabytes-are-a-thing?top_ans=275007184)

Answer (score 53):

Exactly, one of them (G) is power of ten, while the other one (Gi) is power of two. So,

- 10^3 is power of ten. the result is 1000, or 1G
- 2^10 is power of two. the result is 1024, or 1Gi

Comment: This one is neat example

Answer (score 14):

These are different units - one of the are in [Binary prefix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix) and the other are in [Decimal prefix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix#Decimal_prefix).

Simply said, the units such as M, G, T are based on power of 10 - multiplies of 1000. The units such as Mi, Gi, Ti are based on power of 2 - multiplies of 1024.

Comment: Simply said: _bibytes_ are used in Kubernetes configs in order to make it less intuitive for humans to understand how many bytes they really mean. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

> A “kibibyte” is equal to 1024, or 2^10, bytes. Simple enough, but isn’t a “kilobyte” also 1024 bytes? Well, it is, sometimes.  As defined by the International System of Units, the prefix “kilo”
> refers to 1000, or 10^3. Most storage manufacturers measure and label
> capacity in base 10 (1 kilobyte = 1000 bytes; 1 megabyte = 1000
> kilobytes; 1 gigabyte = 1000 megabytes; 1 terabyte = 1000 gigabytes).
> RAM vendors and most operating systems, however, use base 2 (1
> kilobyte = 1024 bytes; 1 megabyte = 1024 kilobytes; 1 gigabyte = 1024
> megabytes; 1 terabyte = 1024 gigabytes). (A notable exception to this
> is macOS, which has used base 10 since OS X 10.6.)  So in order to
> know what exactly is meant by “gigabyte”, you need to know the context
> in which the word is being used. If you are talking about raw hard
> drive capacity, a gigabyte is 1000000000 bytes. If you are talking
> about the file system on top of that hard drive, then gigabyte means
> 1073741824 bytes.

[Link to the source.](https://www.logicmonitor.com/blog/what-the-hell-is-a-kibibyte)